# FileStream Read slow in VB

Tags: vb.net, performance

I try to read a File from a network device, and I would ony like to measure the time, it needs to read the file ( so to check the performance of the device + network ).

If I use robocopy, I can see a speed of 120Mbit/s ( via wireshark I can see a Packet size of 32kByte ).

If I use this code:

```
Private Sub LangerVorgang()
    Dim sb As New IO.FileStream(TextBox1.Text, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    sr = sb
    len = sr.Length - 1
    Dim buffer(32768) As Byte
    Dim bytesread As Integer
    pos = sr.Position

    While sr.Position < len
        bytesread = (sr.Read(buffer, 0, 32768))
    End While
    sr.Close()
End Sub
```

I only get about 90Mbit/s, via Wireshark it uses also 32kByte.

This code, runs in a seperate Thread.

Can somebody tell me, why this is slow?

If I make a bigger buffer ( like 1M ) it is faster, but then the measurement is much worse, so I would like to use about 32kByte.

Thank you

Comment: If going for dead-on 32768 byte packets, you actually need `buffer(32767)` because of how `VB.NET` deals with arrays

Comment: You could try using [**another overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0y914c5(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `FileStream` constructor to specify the stream's buffer and that you read the file sequentially. It could improve the performance a bit: `New IO.FileStream(TextBox1.Text, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.Read, 32768, IO.FileOptions.SequentialScan)`